Movie about two brothers who make it rain!
So there are two brothers, goes to a small town and find out there's no crime there. They decide to find an answer and create a unnatural rain from the water they took from that town, and hope that the rain makes people kind and happy, but accidentally the rain makes people have Alzheimer's and become idiots? One brother's always shooting with a camera to document what they do.
I remember a scene which the queen pees herself because of this rain, and after all the events, there were so few people left in the world, like a dystopia movie. 
I think the movie's year is between 2000-2010, American movie, saw it on CNBC.

Any more details? Year? Country\language? Where did you see it? Was it feature length?

Thanks, I'll add it in. I'm asking about the length because you're describing a Stephen King story that AFAIK was only made into a TV episode in 2006.

Oh, no it's a long movie around 1,5 hours. I remember a very famous Hollywood actor is the leading actor

you know what, i think you were right about Stephen King story...

The episode is currently available online, see if it rings any bells.

This is it. Omg thank you Walt. We've been searching for an answer for hours!

No problem, I'll put it up so the question can be resolved.

Aaaand it's a duplicate (sorry, forgot to look)

You're looking for the Nightmares & Dreamscapes episode The End of the Whole Mess from 2006 based on a Stephen King story and starring Ron Livingston and Henry Thomas.

On November 25, 2011, documentary filmmaker Howard Fornoy tells the story of his family, and more specifically of his younger brother Robert. Bobby, a genius from birth, was troubled with the human race's violent tendencies. One day he discovers a small town in Texas with a non-existent crime rate, and he attempts to find out the cause. He finds chemicals in the local water supply that have a calming effect. In an effort to bring about world peace, he decides to spread the chemical worldwide using a volcano eruption. But Bobby's plan has effects he did not forsee. 

The effects are Alzheimer's, which pretty much destroys humanity. The episode is currently available on Youtube. Here are the brothers:

